# In game programming, how can I test whether a heuristic used is consistent or not?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, heuristics, consistency, tic-tac-toe

I have thought of some **heuristics** for a big (higher dimensions) tic-tac-toe game. How do I check which of them are actually ***consistent***?

What is meant by **consistency** anyways?

Comment: This is a real question.

Comment: Two people have flagged this to be closed as 'not a real question'. I disagree with them too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED: This answer confused admissibility and consistency. I have corrected it to refer to admissibility, but the original question was about consistency, and this answer does not fully answer the question.

You could do it analytically, by distinguishing all different cases and thereby *proving* that your heuristic is indeed admissible.

For informed search, a heuristic is admissible with a search problem (say, the search for the best move in a game) if and only if it **underestimates** the 'distance' to a suitable state.

EXAMPLE: Search for the shortest route to a target city via a network of highways between cities. Here, one could use the Eucidean distance as a heuristic: the length of a straight line to the goal is always shorter or equally long than the best possible way.

Admissibility is required by algorithms like [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*), which then quarantuee you to be optimal (i.e. they will find the best 'route' to a goal state if one exists).

I would recommend to look the topic up in an [AI textbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137903952).

Comment: There is a distinction between admissible & consistent heuristics too, although all consistent heuristics are admissible.  Admissible means the heuristic underestimates the total path cost and it's consistent if the heuristic decreases by no more than the step cost after traversing a step.

Answer (score 1):

Heuristics produce some sort of cost value for a given state. Consistency in this context means the estimate for a state plus the cost of moving to the next state is less than or equal to the estimate for that new state. If this wasn't true then it would imply that - if the heuristic was accurate - that transitioning from one state to the next could incur negative cost, which is typically impossible or incorrect.

This is intuitive to prove when it comes to pathfinding, as you expect every step along the path to take some time, therefore the estimate at step 1 must be lower than the estimate at any step 2. It's probably a bit more complex for tic-tac-toe since you probably have to arbitrarily decide what constitutes a 'cost' in your system. If your heuristic can go both up or down as a result of playing a move - eg. because you encode good moves with positive numbers and bad moves with negative numbers - then your heuristic cannot be consistent.

However, lack of a consistent heuristic is not always a problem. You may not be guaranteed of reaching an optimal solution without one, but it may still speed up the search compared to a brute force state search.